# C preprocessor directive to conditionally compile method calls with square brackets

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I know I can use preprocessor macros to conditionally compile certain method calls, for example:

```
#if SOMETHING
#define fmod(...)
#endif
...
fmod(34.0, 452.0); //this line doesn't get compiled if SOMETHING != 0.
```

Can I use the same procedure to conditionally compile method calls with opening and closing brackets?

Say I'd like to conditionally compile all calls to the class `MyClass`:

```
[MyClass doSomething];
[MyClass doSomethingElse];
```

`#define MyClass[...]` produces:

```
[ doSomething];
```

And that's an error. Any thoughts?

Comment: seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What are you trying to accomplish by conditionally compiling messages sent to `MyClass`?

Comment: Look, XY problems are welcome on Stackoverflow as they're ["practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), aside from the fact that they're intellectually valuable. Besides, this is not an XY problem as my problem **is** to conditionally compile messages sent to `MyClass`.

Comment: FYI, the square bracket notation is not supported in C++ nor in C.  Which language are you writing in?

Comment: The language is Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround rely on fact that calling method on `nil` is no operation

```
@interface MyClassImpl : NSObject

+ (void)doSomething;

@end

#if SOMETHING
#define MyClass MyClassImpl
#else
#define MyClass ((Class)Nil)
#endif
```

Comment: Nice try but that doesn't work because you can't send a message to `nil` at build time. Your code compiles down to `[Nil doSomething];` and I get a build error: `Bad receiver type 'void *'`

Comment: @Eric I have no idea why `Nil` have type of `void *` instead of `Class`, but can you try the updated answer? Otherwise you can have `Class globalNilClass = Nil; #define MyClass globalNilClass`

Answer (score 0):

You won't have any luck overloading the square brackets with macros, but you can flesh out your macro to have the effect you want with different syntax. Conditionally define a macro that takes an argument. In one case, the macro will resolve to just the argument, in the other case, the macro will resolve to white space.

(Edited to use variadic macro)

```
#define COMPILE_CONDITIONAL

#if defined(COMPILE_CONDITIONAL)
  #define conditional(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
  #define conditional(...) 
#endif
```

Then your use cases would look like:

```
conditional(fmod(34.0, 452.0));

conditional(MyClass doSomething);
conditional(MyClass doSomethingElse);
```

You will probably end up using a shorter macro than "conditional" typing that on every line gets old fast.

Comment: I get a `Use of undeclared identifier 'x'` error when I try your code.

Comment: you need to make it variadic macros to allow have `,` inside the macro